# How to convert the below text string into a date type using SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, string, date, sql-server-2016

```
ActivateDate        ShipDate                Month   Month_Length    Day-2c  Day-2c_Length   YEAR-201x   SHIPDateConcatenate     ActivateDateConcatenate
NULL                6/12/2018 12:00:00 AM   6       1               12      2               2018        6-12-2018               NULL
NULL                6/12/2018 12:00:00 AM   6       1               12      2               2018        6-12-2018               NULL
NULL                6/12/2018 12:00:00 AM   6       1               12      2               2018        6-12-2018               NULL
NULL                6/12/2018 12:00:00 AM   6       1               12      2               2018        6-12-2018               NULL
NULL                6/12/2018 12:00:00 AM   6       1               12      2               2018        6-12-2018               NULL
NULL                6/12/2018 12:00:00 AM   6       1               12      2               2018        6-12-2018               NULL
NULL                6/12/2018 12:00:00 AM   6       1               12      2               2018        6-12-2018               NULL
10/12/2018 14:45    10/16/2018 12:00:00 AM  10      2               16      2               2018        10-16-2018              10-12-2018
```

The two columns [ActivateDate] and [ShipDate] datatype is listed below; however each time I try to use convert() or cast() to a date type, a conversion error occurs.

```
SELECT
    [ActivateDate], -- '10/12/2018 14:45' nvarchar(100)
    [ShipDate], -- '6/12/2018 12:00:00 AM'   nvarchar(100)
    SUBSTRING(iedimpr.[ShipDate],CHARINDEX('/', iedimpr.[ShipDate])-2,2) as 'Month',
    LEN(SUBSTRING(iedimpr.[ShipDate],CHARINDEX('/', iedimpr.[ShipDate])-2,2)) as 'Month_Length',
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(iedimpr.[ShipDate],CHARINDEX('/', iedimpr.[ShipDate])+1,2),'/','') as 'Day-2c',
    LEN(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(iedimpr.[ShipDate],CHARINDEX('/', iedimpr.[ShipDate])+1,2),'/','')) as 'Day-2c_Length',
    SUBSTRING(iedimpr.[ShipDate],CHARINDEX('/201', iedimpr.[ShipDate])+1,4) as 'YEAR-201x',
    SUBSTRING(iedimpr.[ShipDate],CHARINDEX('/', iedimpr.[ShipDate])-2,2)
+'-'+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(iedimpr.[ShipDate],CHARINDEX('/', iedimpr.[ShipDate])+1,2),'/','') 
+'-'+SUBSTRING(iedimpr.[ShipDate],CHARINDEX('/201', iedimpr.[ShipDate])+1,4) as 'SHIPDateConcatenate',
    SUBSTRING(iedimpr.[ActivateDate],CHARINDEX('/', iedimpr.[ActivateDate])-2,2)
+'-'+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(iedimpr.[ActivateDate],CHARINDEX('/', iedimpr.[ActivateDate])+1,2),'/','') 
+'-'+SUBSTRING(iedimpr.[ActivateDate],CHARINDEX('/201', iedimpr.[ActivateDate])+1,4) as 'ActivateDateConcatenate'
```

Comment: `6/12/2018` - Is it December 6th or Jun 12th? Same question for `6-12-2018`.
Also, why are you storing dates as strings? Store dates as date and dates + times as datetime2.

Comment: Good Morning, That is my point. The original data is nvarchar(100) and want to convert it into a date. I initially tried convert(date,[shipdate]) and convert(nvarchar(10),[shipdate],102) but neither seemed to work. In the interium, I tried to at least separate the number as a workaround to convert to a date.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question again I've noticed the sample data is ill-formatted, so I've edited it. During this edit I found that you are using american style (`mm/dd/yyyy`) for your string representation of dates.

To convert a valid string representation of DateTime with this format into date, you need to use `101` as the [`style`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles) parameter in the `convert` method.
However, I highly recommend using [`Try_convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of `Convert`, since it will simply return `null` when the value can't be converted instead of raising an error.

That being said, here is an example:

First, create and populate sample data(**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ActivateDate nvarchar(100),
    ShipDate nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @T(ActivateDate, ShipDate) VALUES
(NULL,                  '6/12/2018 12:00:00 AM'),
('10/12/2018 14:45',    '10/16/2018 12:00:00 AM'),
('20/14/2018 14:45',    '10/16/2018 12:00:00 AM'), -- invalid ActivateDate
('2/4/2018 14:45',      '10/16/ZOIB 12:00:00 AM') -- invalid ShipDate
```

The query:

```
SELECT  ActivateDate, 
        ShipDate,
        TRY_CONVERT(datetime, ActivateDate, 101) As DateActiveDate,
        TRY_CONVERT(datetime, ShipDate, 101) As DateShipDate
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
ActivateDate        ShipDate                    DateActiveDate          DateShipDate
NULL                6/12/2018 12:00:00 AM       NULL                    12.06.2018 00:00:00
10/12/2018 14:45    10/16/2018 12:00:00 AM      12.10.2018 14:45:00     16.10.2018 00:00:00
20/14/2018 14:45    10/16/2018 12:00:00 AM      NULL                    16.10.2018 00:00:00
2/4/2018 14:45      10/16/ZOIB 12:00:00 AM      04.02.2018 14:45:00     NULL
```

If you only need `Date` (without the time part), simply use `try_convert(date, ...)` instead of `try_convert(datetime, ...)`.